# Select full row based on MAX value and GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by, max

Here's the scenario. I have employees and they evaluated yearly for different categories. I need: the full row of the latest evaluation for each category.

Example:

Employee Table:

```
EmpID  Name
454    John
```

Evals Table:

```
id EmpID  Category  EvalDate     Note
1  454       A      2016-01-01   Excellent
2  454       A      2017-02-15   Not so good
3  454       B      2016-01-01   Poor
4  454       B      2017-02-01   Good
```

I need a query that returns the latest eval (the full row) for each category:

```
EmpID  Category  EvalDate     Note
454       A      2017-02-15   Not so good
454       B      2017-02-01   Good
```

My query so far:

```
SELECT 
    evals.EmpID,
    evals.Category,
    evals.Note,
    MAX(evals.EvalDate) as LatestEval
FROM
    evals
WHERE 
    evals.EmpID = 454
GROUP BY
    evals.Category
```

This unfortunately returns the latest date for each category but the note field from older evals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: @Uueerdo, not sure that's quite the same, I need grouping on multiple columns, empID and category.

Comment: That answer should still work; it just becomes a matter of joining on all grouped fields.

Comment: @Uueerdo, you are correct. I figured it out, based on that question,I added a field in the group by in the sub-select AND a match on the inner join. The results are wicked fast too. Sloan's answer works too but I get 5 seconds on that query (11500 rows) and I get 0.4 seconds on this one. Thank you!

Comment: Sloane's answer is probably slower because the subquery is *correlated*; this often ends up in the subquery being executed repeatedly (for each external result). joining to an uncorrelated query (that groups all) ends up with a subquery that can take slightly longer to executed BUT is only executed once. _(On ridiculously large tables, correlated versions can be faster, especially if the outer query results in relatively few executions of the subquery.)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might give this a try:

```
SELECT
    evals.EmpID,
    evals.Category,
    evals.Note,
    evals.EvalDate
FROM Employee emp
JOIN Evals evals
ON emp.EmpID = evals.EmpID
AND eval.EvalDate = 
    (SELECT MAX(EvalDate) 
    FROM Evals a 
    WHERE a.Category = evals.category 
        AND a.EmpID = emp.EmpID GROUP BY e.EmpID,e.Category)
GROUP BY evals.EmpID,evals.Category
```

Comment: I believe the problem here is that it doesn't do any grouping by category, this will return just the latest eval regardless of category.

Comment: I would also add to the where in the subselect to match on the category

Comment: If that works for you, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I assume that the 'group by e.empid' is actually group by a.empid, right?

Comment: Yep, typo on my part - fat fingers I guess :-)

Comment: Same for the other e.'s in the subselect.